# Casting values in an HQL Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I'm running the following as part of the where clause of an HQL query:

```
:timeToTopOfList = ((CAST((j.displayed_position - 1) AS FLOAT) / jp.openings_per_month) * 30)
```

When I run it in SQL Management studio it works just fine, but when I run it through eclipse I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:55)

I'm also using JPA, and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791425/573634) you cannot convert types if you're using JPA. Is that true?

I really need to divide two int value columns as a float.

Comment: Is it part of the select clause or of the where clause?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's part of the where clause.

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue when casting to string.

It was resolved by typing in 'string' in lower case.

Try with lower case 'float'

Check out the below link for an explanation:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=960362