# casting resultset from int to boolean in hql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

if I have formula like this:

```
@Formula("select count(1) from Market m where m.defaultAirportCode=airportCode")
private Boolean isDefault;
```

Is there any way to cast result of my select to boolean? I would like to return true or false instead of 1 or 0, cause i need to map it on Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793868/2503659

Depending on your database, you may need to set up a mapping: http://www.coderanch.com/t/218458/ORM/databases/Mapping-oracle-boolean-Java-boolean