# JPA OR condition with single value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a table company: `companyId number`, `companyName varchar`, `address nvarchar`.
I want to achieve a goal that user can query to fetch company either using a id or company name, image there is a search box, user only has to input a single value, then it will fetch company information.

I wrote an repository

```
@Query(value = "select c from CompanyBasicInfo c where c.companyID = ?1 or c.companyName = ?1 ")
List<CompanyBasicInfo> findByCompanyIDOrCompanyName(@PathVariable String input);
```

But when I query, I got an error: `Parameter value [10083769] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]`

How can I solve this problem? Most of the materials available are something like 
`findByFirstnameOrLastname` which uses two values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's either by `id` OR by `company name`, why don't you just wrap the method call in an _if-statement_ checking if the Search-Param (String) consists solely out of numbers? :o

Comment: the `@PathVariable` looks rather odd. The issue is because company ID is a Long, you cannot "=" it with a string "?1". You could probably hack your way in using `select c from CompanyBasicInfo c where CAST(c.companyID AS String)= ?1 or c.companyName = ?1`

Comment: @RC This would work but should be discouraged because using an analytical function on a search criteria is inefficient.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle that's why I said "hack your way in" :)

Comment: @Seth, we provide a service to front-side, so the logic you said could be done there, but provide one single service and let the front-side just invokes the service is kind of cool and simple. :)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle  Thanks . The way you provide is good! But how to make it efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the companies have a name which consists only of digits, you can create 2 methods (by companyId / by company name) and check wether your input is a number.

If you do not want to do this, you can use the "2 params" version :

```
List<CompanyBasicInfo> findByCompanyIDOrCompanyName(Long companyId, String companyName);
```

Then parse your input :

```
List<CompanyBasicInfo> find(String input) {
  Long companyId = null;
  try {
    companyId = Long.valueOf(input);
  } catch(Exception ignored){}

  return repository.findByCompanyIDOrCompanyName(companyId, input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem of parameters amount but of its type

You can try to treat companyId as String in query using *cast* function like here.
[How do I write hql query with cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791325/how-do-i-write-hql-query-with-cast)

Your code will look like

```
@Query(value = "select c from CompanyBasicInfo c where cast(c.companyID as String) = ?1 or c.companyName = ?1 ")
List<CompanyBasicInfo> findByCompanyIDOrCompanyName(@PathVariable String input);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include code that helps rather than just linking to another similar answer.